# PHP form with curl

Tags: php, forms, curl

I would like to show a simple form in .php file if my current url is different than "https://www.example.com/". So first of all i have a cURL request

```
$ch = curl_init();
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookiePath));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookiePath));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLoginRedirect);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $commonHeaders);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) { die (curl_error($ch)); }
$actualUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

$additionalHeaders = array(
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Referer: ' . $actualUrl,
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
); 

$postData = 'email=email@example.com&password=my_password&_rememberMe=on&rememberMe=on&_eventId=submit&gCaptchaResponse=';
$headers = array_merge($commonHeaders, $additionalHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $actualUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) { die (curl_error($ch)); }
$actualUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
echo $actualUrl;

if($actualUrl !== 'https://www.example.com/')
{
    // Show form and send post request with data
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

And here is the question. Is there a way to not reload this .php file when form is filled, and if not - should I call curl_init() again or not?

// EDIT

```
> I want to log into a website. First of all i send get request to get
> url and then post request to fill a form. Then from actual url i can
> check if i need to verify my account - if so, i get a special number
> to my email and i have to do another post request with this number but
> everything without closing an actual session. Can I send a reference
> of $ch to another file? Because if i send form data to self .php file
> connection will be closed (even if i do it with jquery/ajax i
> believe).
> 
> Thanks.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve - the code looks like simulating a login submit, but the page refresh has nothing to do with it. You can submit the form using javascript and make an AJAX request to call the php and get the result

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to not reload

It's will be posible if you will use JavaScript. Look for examples JQuery+AJAX, it's a simple way.